# Making a desk that open

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing, unreal-engine

Hi I've been trying to make a desk for a game I'm making in unreal engine 4, but I've been having some problems. I made the drawer, and the cabinet separate objects, and wan't to animate them opening. I did that, and merged the object, but it started moving the desk, instead of just the drawer. How do I make the animation work?

Comment: How did you animate the drawer? because when you merge it all into one object, that is going to be causing some problems for the animation.

Comment: You can't expect the animated drawer to keep woking after you merge it with another object

Comment: Thx for the replies, yah I figured that out, now I'm just trying to figure out how i ma going to animate it. I have a cabinet, a drawer, and a desk, but there separate. I wan't it so that they are together, can I do this somehow with bone?

Comment: Ok something was wrong with my design and I had to delete it anyway for me to do this form the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that each part of your desk which articulates relative to any other part of the desk will need to be a separate object, and parented to some other appropriate part of the desk. But having written that , the exact method of associating the various parts of your desk so that they articulate as you expect in UE4 will be determined by the design of the UE4 game engine. I suggest that when you have completed all of the constituent parts of your desk that you ask about animating them on a forum devoted to UE4 topics.

Comment: Ok thx I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

I can explain from my end but I use Unity 3D and I am sure it will give you some information:

When I am working on creating props for my games in Unity 3D, let's say if it's a desk and it's drawer needs to open (like the player can interact with it). I separate the 'drawer'from the desk because then I am able to animate it separately in Blender 3D or Unity 3D.

Later in Unity 3D, I can combine the desk + the animated drawer = Prefab.

Hope it's helpful... Good Luck